# Using a grep-like tool to remove surrounding lines

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm using gcov to get the code coverage results from my program, it works great but I want to remove the results from files that have 0% coverage.

It prints off the desired output to stdout, but I get the additional output in the format

```
File [directory]
Lines executed:0.00% of [lines]
[newline]
```

And that is the output I want to remove. There are other Files, but their coverage value is greater than 0.00% and therefore I want them to stay. I just want the line before and after 0.00% to be removed.

So I basically want to do `grep -v -C 1 :0.00%`

Except that isn't working, `grep -C 1 :0.00%` matches what I want to remove, and `grep -v :0.00%` removes just the 0% lines, but they don't work together. Is there another grep-like tool that does this or do I just have the format wrong?

Comment: Why not just include required output from sample input in your question? Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean when I use grep -v -C 1? It doesn't do anything, the whole output is returned.

Comment: I mean "we know what you have" but "we don't know what you want it to look like" when you're done ; -). Good luck.

Comment: Oh I just want it to go away. The line before and after :0.00% should be removed, there are other lines, but they are greater than 0% and therefore I want them to stay.

Comment: Last time I'll say it, Include your required output from your sample input in your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want the line before and after 0.00% to be removed.

You could use GNU sed:

```
sed 'N;/\n.*0.00%.*/!{P;D};N;d' inputfile
```

Comment: I ended up using `paste - - -` however I tested this and that's what I originally asked for. Thanks

Comment: @GriffinG Wouldn't `paste` mess up other lines too?  Or did you split those later?

Comment: @potong Completely useless.  Mismatched copy paste it seems.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS;

```
$ cat file
foo
File [directory]
Lines executed:0.00% of [lines]
[newline]
bar

$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{sub(/[^\n]+\n[^\n]+:0.00%[^\n]+\n[^\n]+\n/,"")}1' file
foo
bar
```

The above just looks for the RE that describes a line containing `:0.00%` (i.e. `[^\n]+:0.00%[^\n]+\n`) and then removes it along with the line before it (i.e. `[^\n]+\n`) and the line after it (same RE).